# How to get value from the json encode function

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

> I am getting This Type Of json format From My query Now I want to use 
>   Value Of top How can i get it from the json format:

```
Json format I am Getting :

{"p":{"r":true,"rows":[{"id":"1","gop":"Contents","top":"p is simply dummy ","no":"1"}]}}
```

> What M doing In Response like:

```
success:function(data){
          var obj=$.parseJSON(data);
          var privacyss='';
 if(obj.p.res){
 var privacyss='<p>'+p.rows.top+'</p>';
 $("#Privacys").html(privacyss);  
}
 }
```

> But Am Not able Get The Value Through  p.rows.top .. So please Let me
>   know How to get the value

Comment: You have apply result inside if(obj.p.res){ this condition are you sure is there res key exist in your p array ?

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
obj.p.rows[0].top
```

Answer (score 0):

USE This way

var privacyss = '

'+p.rows[0].top'+'

';

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data={"p":{"r":true,"rows":[{"id":"1","gop":"Contents","top":"p is simply dummy ","no":"1"}]}};

// gives entire object
console.log(data.p.rows[0]);

// access individual key
console.log(data.p.rows[0].top);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `rows` is array of objects. So you should use index after `rows` to fetch. In your code change this `obj.p.res` to `obj.p.rows[0].top`.
2. Second is you used `p.res`, in response there's no res, instead use `rows`.

See below code for reference.

```js
var response = '{"p":{"r":true,"rows":[{"id":"1","gop":"Contents","top":"p is simply dummy ","no":"1"}]}}';

var resParsed = JSON.parse(response); 
console.log(resParsed.p.rows[0].top);
```

Answer (score 0):

simply you can call it by

```
obj.p.rows[0].top
```

but what if rows have multiple index so don't bound with index use each or map for this

like :

```
{"r":true,"rows":[{"id":"1","gop":"Contents","top":"p is simply dummy ","no":"1"}, {"id":"2","gop":"Contents","top":"p is other simply dummy ","no":"2"}]}}
```

do like this

```
success:function(data){
    var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    if(obj.p.res){
        $.each(obj.p.rows, function (i, row) {
            var privacyss='<p>'+row.top+'</p>';
            $("#Privacys").append(privacyss);  // you can call html() too but it will overrite html 
        });
    }
}
```

> Suggestion

if you are dealing with JSON then use `dataType : 'JSON'`

```
url : url,
dataType : 'JSON', // add this field
success:function(data){
    // var obj = JSON.parse(data); you don't need to parse it 
    data.p.res // can access attribute 
}
```